# Power BI Search Box

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to create a search bar on power bi.
The user inputs ID, which filters a table viz I have created.
The search bar must not have a drop down feature.
The result should only display table values for the ID typed in.
If no ID is typed in, the table must remain EMPTY.

I have tried using slicer and text filter add in.
However, when cleared, the entire table contents are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a measure similar to:

```
Is Filtered = IF(CALCULATE(ISFILTERED('YourTable'), ALLSELECTED('YourTable')), "yes")
```

Then add this measure as a Visual Filter to your Table visual, and set it to `is not blank`.